# Can't load a previous project with QGIS 3.18.2 with versions 3.24.3. 3.20.0 3.22.0. No layers and just a white screen

Tags: qgis, qgs, loading

With QGIS 3.18.2 I have created a map point cloud data with contours. I saved, Lakach_East_West_IntRas_Clip-3-24-32, and closed the project. A few months later, now using 3.24.3 I wanted to continue working on this project. It is shown to me under "recent projects" too. Now I want to open it, but the project does not load anything. No layers, just a white screen. There is also no query "Defend defective layers". Does anyone have an idea how to get the project up and running again? I have also tried it with 3.20 and 3.22 with no indication of what the problem is. There are no special characters in the file name, however, the size is 600,000 KB.

Comment: How did you create your data ? Are you sure you didn't use memory layer ? ( If that's the case they are now lost...)

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. I can reload the project again with 3.18 with no problem and nothing is lost. All I have are 2 types of files: West_66300_65300_1Prelay_FL_West_66017-65017_1_Contour — contour, and Prelay_FL_West_66017-65017_Int-Ras_Clip.tif. What I have noticed that the 3.18 is QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.18.1-1-Setup-x86.exe 2021-03-20 20:19 339M  and the 3.24 is QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.24.3-1.msi 2022-05-14 13:38 1.0G  . Not sure as they are different setup installation files the 3.24.3 doesn't want to load the project.

Comment: Creating a new, empty project in 3.24, can you just open the layers (the data, not the project)? Just to see if the problem is on the side of the data or the project.